# Get width and height of child component with NgIf applied

Tags: angular

I have a parent component with a child that populates itself using `NgFor`. The parent defines a property `childIsVisible = false` and binds the child to it with `*ngIf="childIsVisible"` so initially the child is not displayed.

Later on I want to flip `childIsVisible` to `true` so that the child component appears and I want to position the child based on it's width.

My problem is that within the parent method that flips the visibility I can't get the child's width because it not yet being displayed. What I want is some method of toggling visibility on then, once the child component is being displayed, get its width and position it accordingly.

I have looked at using `AfterContentChecked` but this seems a bit heavy handed as it is called pretty much constantly.

Hope this makes sense, any thoughts on different ways to approach this would be great.

Cheers

Comment: if you could show something in plunker.

Comment: I can't get my head around plnkr. Tried to set something up using the NG2 template but anything I add seems to break it and I can't work out how to debug anything I write. Will have another crack at it though, I know its pretty pointless trying to describe this stuff without examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe `[hidden]="!childIsVisible"` could solve problem. It will be presented in DOM, just will be invisible until `childIsVisible` will switch to `true`. Let me know your results!

Comment: This does the job, though I literally just finished reading [some blog post](http://angularjs.blogspot.se/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html) that claimed this was a bad idea and to use `ngIf` instead.

Comment: Just a fast solution. Not a big deal, but you are right, sir. `ngIf` is better practice, I think it just could be the case for your task. Let me know if you will find something more elegant!

Comment: It is a totally valid answer and I'm all about the quick fix at this stage. I'm going with it for now with a note to investigate more later on. Cheers for your help